# Does black seed oil help in regrowing hair on bald regions of the scalp?

Tags: hair, oil

From: http://oilhealthbenefits.com/black-seed-oil/

"Black seed oil may help in regrowing hair on bald regions of the scalp"

Is this claim true?

Comment: Related: [Does black seed oil help treat various cancers, asthma, epilepsy, liver conditions, high blood pressure and more?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5287)